# Can I work with multiple .html in a view using Materialize?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, materialize

I have an AngularJS application using Materialize, I have a module named: reports, then there's a view named: reports.html where I will put all my reports. The problem is that I don't want to put all the code of the reports inside reports.html, I want to modularize it using multiple .html files like: report1.html, report2.html, report3.html. How can I do this to include or use that files inside reports.html (without using iframes) and passing parameters to that view (reports.html)?

Thanks.

Comment: this question feels really broad.  I would probably start off with, have you tried using `ng-include`? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using angular.js can't you just use an [angular include](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_includes.asp) within your `/reports.html`?

```
<div ng-include="'reports2.html'"></div>
```